# CastleDynamic only get the virtual values

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

While I'm testing the Castle DynamicProxy I found an weird behavior

I didn't found good documentation, so the closer information I found was theses 2 ask
[Castle Dynamic Proxy not intercepting method calls when invoked from within the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633914/castle-dynamic-proxy-not-intercepting-method-calls-when-invoked-from-within-the/)
and
[Why won't DynamicProxy's interceptor get called for *each* virtual method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153019/why-wont-dynamicproxys-interceptor-get-called-for-each-virtual-method-call)

and with it, I suppose that, when you use the **CreateClassProxyWithTarget** everything goes into the Class and back to the proxy, so if the Prop/function is not virtual, it only return the Class value.

I guess, with code sample, my question get clear.

Let's suppose I have this code

Main

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var theObj = new SomeClass
    {
        NonVirtualString = "Non virtual value",
        VirtualString = "Virtual value"
    };
    var theProxy = Interceptor.AddProxy(theObj);

    Console.WriteLine($"OBJ NonVirtualString: {theObj.NonVirtualString } || VisrtualString {theObj.VirtualString }");
    Console.WriteLine($"Proxy NonVirtualString: {theProxy.NonVirtualString } || VisrtualString {theProxy.VirtualString }");
}


public class SomeClass
{
    public string NonVirtualString { get; set; }
    public virtual string VirtualString { get; set; }
}
```

Interceptor

```
public static class Interceptor
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator _generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    public static TEntity AddProxy<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity: class, new()
    {
        var proxy = _generator.CreateClassProxyWithTarget(entity, new LogInterceptor());
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

Logger

```
[Serializable]
public class LogInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            Console.WriteLine("Intercepting: {0} with value: {1}", invocation.Method.Name, invocation.ReturnValue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception in method {0}{1}{2}", invocation.Method.Name,
                                            Environment.NewLine, ex.Message));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

the result is

> OBJ NonVirtualString: **Non virtual value** || VisrtualString Virtual value
>
> Intercepting: get_VirtualString with value: Virtual value
>
> Proxy NonVirtualString: **NULL** || VisrtualString Virtual value

And the expected result would be

> OBJ NonVirtualString: **Non virtual value** || VisrtualString Virtual value
>
> Intercepting: get_VirtualString with value: Virtual value
>
> Proxy NonVirtualString:  **Non virtual value**  || VisrtualString Virtual value

**So, if the result is right, how I can do, with Castle or other Lib what I'm trying(Only overhide the virtual and keep the non virtual accessible ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't. Not with the composition-based `CreateClassProxyWithTarget`, anyway. When you are calling a non-virtual method on such a proxy object, you're completely bypassing DynamicProxy; it cannot intercept that invocation and therefore won't forward it to the target object. Thus you get back the value of the proxy object's own uninitialized `NonVirtualString` property.

You could get this to work with inheritance-based proxying, i.e. with `CreateClassProxy`. Using that approach, you'll only have one object (the proxy) instead of two, so you'd set the property values directly on the proxy object instead of on a separate target. Then, even though DynamicProxy still won't be able to intercept the call to `NonVirtualString`'s getter, the call will just use the original class' getter.

Answer (score 0):

Because the property is not virtual the proxy class cannot override it. When you call `Interceptor.AddProxy()` it creates a *new* object of type that inherits from `SomeClass`. This object will have its own values of `VirtualString` and `NonVirtualString`. `VirtualString` Will be overridden by the library to use Interceptor, but `NonVirtualString` will not be overriden and will remain NULL, as it's the default for string.

You might try to use Interface interception instead. Otherwise, you won't be able to intercept a non virtual methods/properties.